# How to prove the Cantor-Lebesgue function is well defined?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> The Cantor-Lebesgue function is defined on $\mathcal{C}$ by:
> $$F(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{b_k}{2^k} \quad \textrm{if $x =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k3^{-k}$, where $b_k = \frac{a_k}{2}$}.$$
> In this definiton ,we choose the expansion of $x$ in which $a_k = 0$ or $2$

We wang to show that this define is well-defined and continuous on $\mathcal{C}$.
First ,we can prove that $F(x)$ is converges.Indeed , we have :
$$|\frac{a_k}{2^{k+1}}|\le |\frac{1}{2^k}|$$
Since $\sum \frac{1}{2^k}$,is converges ,$F(x)$ is converges.
However ,my question is that the tenary expression of $[0,1]$ is not unique ,so we want to prove that if $x$ have two different ternary expressions ,which images is the same?

I first attempt that if $x$ have two different expression ,such as $x_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k^13^{-k}$ and $x_2 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k^23^{-k}$,and $x_1 = x_2$.We consider
$F(x_1)$ and $F(x_2)$.Since $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k^13^{-k}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k^23^{-k}= 0$,we naturally want to establish the relationship between $F(x_1)-F(x_2)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k^13^{-k}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k^23^{-k} = 0$.

But unfortunately ,I can't establish the relationship above.

Can you help me or tall us other solvtion about this question.

Comment: Just think of which are the cases where the expansion is not unique, then it is not hard to check that in this specific case things work out for $F(x)$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I checke out the ternary expression in cantor set ,meybe the ternary expression in cantor set is unique.Are right?

Comment: Yes the ternary expression is unique.

Comment: yeah,I know what happened.